# add exposition text to pie chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, pie-chart

I'm working with a humorous dataset from fivethirtyeight.com that discusses which and how often Marvel Comic characters have died through the years. For reference, the dataset is located here:

Now, I'm working with a very simple pie chart that shows how the ratio of characters that have/haven't died. I've already sliced the data, which exists withing zero_deaths and one_death.

```
labels = 'Never Died', 'Died at Least Once'
stats = [len(zero_deaths), len(one_death)]
plt.pie(stats, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title('Percentage of Marvel Comics Characters (173) that Have/Have Not Died')
```

Instead of having the size of the dataset in the title of the graph, I want to add some text to the side of the pie chart to let a viewer know that the dataset is for 173 total characters. My questions would be:

A. How would I implement this? I can find ways to annotate the chart segments but not how to just add a little exposition next to the graph
B. Is such a thing even in good practice? Perhaps the accepted standard is to include it in the title?

Comment: It is often easier to make the graph using python, and add additional annotation/flavor using some sort of image editor/manipulator.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is good information for the future for me to remember! Unfortunately, this is for a class I'm taking this summer, so all visualizations must be entirely within a python environment. The question isn't how to add the annotation, but to increase the appeal of my visualization, I would very much like to know how to answer my original question, if possible.

Comment: SO is not well suited to ask question of the kind "what do you think is best...". I guess here you need to take responsibility: Decide for a solution that you are able to defend against critizism and implement it. Concerning implementation, I'm not sure if it is completely clear what you want to achieve. A (hand) drawing of what you imagine your plot to look like might be helpful. (Also, your link does not appear in the text.)

Comment: Rereading the question, it might be that you are just looking for something like `plt.text(0.7,0.7, "My text here")`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm sad the answer was so simple, but even more sad that over an hour of searching wasn't able to find such an easy addition to solve my problem. Thanks!